# What Mathematica purchase level does CDF creation and deployment come with?

Tags: cdf-format, deployment, webmathematica, enterprise-cdf

I am evaluating which purchase level of Mathematica 9 will suit my needs. I am finding some of the information provided on [Mathematica's How to Buy Chart](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/how-to-buy/industry-individuals.html?ctry=US) a bit vague and unclear.

I need to be able to create interactive visualizations and then be able to deploy them in a webpage for others to use. I am assuming CDFs are the best choice for this (although webMathematica seems like it can do this as well). Do I need the *standard* or *enterprise* purchase level to be able to create and deploy these CDFs?

It would also be a bonus for those accessing and interacting with the CDFs to be able to save and/or print them. Which of the packages provide this?

Any light that can be shed on what each of the industry packages (standard and enterprise) provides is much appreciated.

Comment: you are probably better off asking Wolfram Research directly; this place is not affiliated with them and you are unlikely to get a definitive answer (unless someone happens to know, by chance)

Comment: I will see if I can contact them directory, nevertheless, I think a community of mathematica users is a great place to get an answer to a question like this. This should be answerable based on the kind of package that a person has and what capabilities it provides.

Comment: certainly, that's why I said that you'll get an answer if someone happens to know (I know at least a couple who do). but asking WRI directly is probably more reliable (eg, the people who frequent this place and are familiar with this may not see your question, etc)

Comment: Perhaps one of Rolf/PFonseca/AlbertR/MikeH/Murta might know about enterprise CDF/webMathematica... hopefully one of them will see this question.

Comment: @murta seems to have Enterprise.

Comment: And @rolfmertig develops for webMathematica.

Comment: I also played with Enterprise. It is really good. But I am really not sure if this type of question should be asked here. If something is vague unclear the OP should contact Wolfram. Or maybe he is also like most others that don't want to contact software companies? He might belong to that probably very very small minority. I love to contact software companies.

Comment: @RolfMertig I think contacting them is great advice, I just also hoped to get information from actual users as well. Plus, I hope this question will save others the trouble when considering different mathematica packages.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends on what you want to do with CDF documents.

The standard version of Mathematica allows you to make CDF documents. A good example of what they can do is the stuff on demonstrations.wolfram.com. Basically, if you are content with making Manipulate statements with sliders and buttons, then you'll do well with the standard CDF document. You can deploy them on a webpage just like youll see in the demonstrations webpage.

If you want to make something more complicated, then you need enterprise CDF. Some common things you may want to do which would require Enterprise CDF:

- Importing/Exporting Data
- Having input fields

Comment: Thanks @RolfMertig, that is a feature I'd like to consider having available.

Comment: Also saving from CDF Player does need Enterprise generated CDF. Printing is possible also from FreeCDF's. See also: [here](http://www.wolfram.com/player-pro/how-player-pro-compares.html)